# Kotlin: JSON string with linebreaker and variable

Tags: json, string, kotlin

I would like to add linebreakers to a JSON string so it will be more readable.

```
val myString = "some string"
val myObjectJson = `
{
    "example1": "value",
    "example2": $myString
}`
```

So later I can use ObjectMapper to create an object. `objectMapper.readValue(myObjectJson, MyClass::class.Java)`

What I'm trying to figure out:

1. How to add lineBreaker in Json string?

Tried template literals:"`", doesn't seem to work in Kotline. gives `Expecting an expression` error.

2. How to use variable in Json string?
   This might go away after I figure out how to add linebreakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited because I think I have misunderstood your question).

Are you asking how to lay out a JSON string in the source code?  If so then what you are looking for is the [Raw String feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/strings.html#raw-strings) implemented with 3 double-quotes like this:

```
val myObjectJson = """
{
    "example1": "value",
    "example2": $myString
}
"""
```

But in case you asking

> How to add lineBreaker in Json string?

(Assuming you are using Jackson's ObjectMapper)

1. Simply use `writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()` like this:  `MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(value)`
2. If that is not good enough for you I suppose you could implement a custom Pretty Printer: https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.14.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter.html